# Как с помощью grid расположить данные блоки в ряд с фиксированной шириной?

Tags: css, layout, grid

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cards {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
/*  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(290px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 36px;
  grid-row-gap: 27px; 
}

.card {
  width: 370px;
  padding: 100px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
     <!-- <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div> -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Если блоков `.card` много, то выглядит как надо, но если становится 2, то они растягиваются и появляются отступы. Можно ли добиться такого результата:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 290px));
```

и убрать ширину у карточки:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cards {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(0, 290px));
  grid-column-gap: 36px;
  grid-row-gap: 27px; 
}

.card {
  padding: 40px;
  background: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="cards">
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
     <!-- <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div>
      <div class="card"></div> -->
    </div>
</div>
```